# Azure Service Fabric, KeyVault, SSL Certificates

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-keyvault

I want to secure my own HTTPS end point (node.js express.js server) with a certificate which I have deployed to the cluster (that is, it exists in Cert:\LocalMachine\My).

I of course want to avoid having my certificate in source control. I can't use an `EndpointBindingPolicy` in the ServiceManifest because as far as I'm aware that is just for http.sys(?) based systems, which this isn't.

What I thought is perhaps run a `SetupEntryPoint` script to:

1. grab the certificate from the store
2. export it as a pfx with a random passphrase (or some appropriate format)
3. copy it to {pkgroot}/certs/ssl_cert.pfx
4. replace some sort of token in serverinit.js with the random passphrase

This way the server, er, code base doesn't need to have the certificate present, i  just needs to trust that it will be there when the service is run.

However I don't think I can do this, if it even *is* as sensible idea, as the certificates in the store are marked such that the private key is non-exportable! Or, at least, they are with my RDP account!

Is there a way to export the certificate with its private key?

What are my options here?

---

I ended up writing a powershell script which runs in my release pipeline, arguments are clientID, clientSecret and certificateName. clientSecret is stored as a protected environmental variable for my agent.

1. Create new application registration under same subscription as KeyVault (which should be same as SF Cluster) (e.g. in portal.azure.com)
2. Note down app ID
3. Create app secret
4. Modify KeyVault ACL with App as principal, set get only on secrets
5. use REST api with client ID and secret https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret

I chose this over grabbing the certificate in the SetupEntryPoint, for example, as this hides the client secret better from the open world (e.g. developers who shouldn't/don't need access to it)

Comment: isn't there a way to read a certificate from the store without the need to export it? Like this: https://github.com/jfromaniello/node-windows-certs

Comment: Unsure, I tried to use a powershell script w/ crypt32.dll to force windows to extract the cert incl. private key, but that did not work on the server even when run as LocalSystem account (it extracted the cert, but didn't include the private key -- worked fine on my desktop though), so I would guess this would not either. I shall give it a try though, but edge.js is a pretty hefty library to be pushing every time we deploy a new release!

Comment: An alternate approach could be to just run it as http and put it behind a reverse proxy that supports SSL offloading.

Comment: Reverse proxy would be a good idea, but there's basically only me managing this cluster so I want to keep things as relatively simple as possible! I ended up writing a powershell script executed in my release pipeline which grabs the cert form the keyvault. 3kB certainly beats several 100MB!